# I know a GUID is nearly unique. But is it acceptable practice to assume it is unique?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, guid

So I completely understand the mathematical unlikeliness of creating two [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier) values with the same number.  But is it acceptable practice to assume they are unique?

For example I am working with a system for dealing with medical files.  When I began to layout the database structure the manager (Not very technically knowledgeable, but likes to think he is and delegates things that would be better left for the more technically minded to decide) says he wants to use GUID's to separate different medical records instead of INT because it is "More unique".  I explained how an INT is always going to be unique because it is sequential.  I suggested we use BigINT if it will make him feel more comfortable since there are more numbers in that then if the population of the planet increased to the point people would only fit standing next to one another across the planet, but he is insisting on using GUIDs.

My feeling is although it is NEARLY IMPOSSIBLE for there to be a mix up, when dealing with medical records, why take the chance?  What is the advantage of using a GUID vs an INT in this scenario?

Comment: the advantage is nothing

Comment: Just utilize an auto incrementing primary key. That's what they're there for. The DB will enforce its uniqueness.

Comment: I dig.  I completely understand the issue at hand.  I am just making sure I am not missing something before I take this up a level

Comment: One of the advantages of the GUID would be if you are going to have multiple independent systems running at different hospitals/medical centres. In case of the numeric ids the medical record from one hospital will most likely have the same id form the other. In case of the guids the medical records would be near unique

Comment: take it up a level. Because when you share Sally's medical records to John by mistake, you have HIPAA coming down your throat, and you serve fries

Comment: your manager may read this as well

Comment: @ElGavilan Same could be said for a good database supporting UUID as a native type including indexing. "Just utilize a UUID with default-value from a call to a UUID generating library as primary key."

Comment: You may found useful in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx if you decide to use `GUID`

Comment: Yes, it is safe to assume GUID is always unique. I prefer INT for simplicity and speed, promote to BIGINT for range or use GUID to solve new problems. That is, when I can prove that simple just isn't good enough anymore. If you can get by with simple data structures, you probably should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But is it acceptable practice to assume it is unique?

**Yes.** That is the entire purpose of [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), to be used as a reliable unique identifier without centralized coordination. (A [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) is Microsoft’s variation of a UUID.)

Only you (or your appropriate management) can make the final judgement for your particular project.

But if you truly begin to appreciate the enormity of the numerical range of 12x bits (which is actually incomprehensible to the human mind), then you know you can remove the usage of a properly generated UUID from your list of worries.

By “properly generated” I mean things like using the date-time Versions, or for lower number of values use the random (Version 4) if backed by a cryptographically-strong random number generator. Nearly every modern operating system today includes a UUID generation library. Or you can use the [OSSP UUID](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/) project. *Improperly*-generated would include roll-your-own implementations you may see bandied about the inter webs.

As for the suggestion to use a database’s auto-incrementing serial/sequence number, every database person I know with years of real-world experience has been burned by those. I’ve never heard of or read of anyone ever having a collision with properly-generated UUIDs. I'm not saying sequences are necessarily bad or don't have their place, I'm just saying that all I can do is laugh when I hear people turn away from a UUID because of some beyond-astrononomically incomprehensibly minute possibility of a UUID collision and choose a sequence instead.

> when dealing with medical records, why take the chance?

Your medical system is far far more likely to fail because of faulty data-entry or other human error with handling records. But do you post 3 clerks on duty to independently triple-enter the same data to reduce that chance of error? No. And that risk is incomprehensibly mathematically more likely to happen than a UUID problem. Yet every medical facility I know of accepts that enormous risk without even thinking about it.

> What is the advantage of using a GUID vs an INT

The advantages include:

- No need to manage your sequences.
  Examples include: Resetting for development, test, and production environments. Or when restoring a backup. Or fixing the sequence after faults in the system’s serial generation library (my own experience).
- Avoid users’ intuited assumptions being confused about missing numbers in the sequence. 
  I've had that conversation far too often.
- [Federating data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_database_system) between distributed systems.
  This is the biggest advantage, each system can act independently yet easily share data back and forth with other systems. Without UUIDs, the administrative overhead and the risk of error are bothersome at first and only grow over time.

Downsides include:

- Larger memory and storage usage.
  Serial numbers are usually 32-bit integers, sometimes 64-bit. A [good database](http://www.postgresql.org) with native support for UUID as a data type will use 128 bits.
- Less readable by humans.
  One workaround is to just read several of the first or last digits for casual work.
- Possibly less efficient indexing, with very large number of entries.

Comment: Another option is to use GUIDs and Sequential IDs together, for external and internal identification respectively, though this would represent a denormalization.

Comment: @Dai Yes, doing both a UUID and a sequence can be reasonable in some scenarios. And not necessarily a denormalization. The UUID is the true ID, the primary key. The sequence tells you what order they were added to the database, which is a different meaning/propose than the UUID. Also, having a trigger that automatically records the date-time when the row is created can serve a similar purpose. Just beware that when created and when written can be different moments because of transactions.

Answer (score 4):

using an incrementing integer ID ensures only uniqueness within its own domain/type, an advantage of UUIDs/GUIDs is that they uniquely identify the owning *thing* in the entire universe.

So if you have multiple objects, say `MedicalRecord, ID = 5`, `VaccinationForm, ID = 5` then you need to specify both the type ("medicalRecord" or "vaccinationForm" with the ID value of `5`) whereas with a GUID you only need to store a single quanta of information to uniquely identify it.

It can be argued that using GUIDs is a waste of space as they are 16 bytes long (a 128-bit value).

If your system is self-contained and not interfacing with others you might want to use SQL Server's "sequence" concept, where instead of each table storing its own identity sequence, the sequence is maintained for all tables, making it a Locally-Unique ID value. You can use any size integer too.

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx